# How can I determine the length of a local .wav file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local, wav

I'd like to get to know the length (best in ms) of a .wav-file with a given filepath via JavaScript for a GreaseMonkey Script.

Problem 1) accessing local files
Problem 2) getting length of the wav

Comment: Sorry but this is impossible with just javascript.

Comment: As far as I know, you won't be able to access a local file directly. You may have to use an `<input type="upload">` field, and even that might not work without a server-side workaround (although it may work, I don't know).

Answer (score 2):

There is [jssound](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/jssound) from jslibs package that could help you do this quite easily.

```
 LoadModule('jsstd');
 LoadModule('jsio');
 LoadModule('jssound');

 var file = new File('someSound.wav');
 file.Open('r');
 var pcm = DecodeSound(file);
 file.Close();
 Print('sample length: '+pcm.length, '\n');
```